# Inferring types in a python program

Tags: python

I am working on static analysis with python. My objective is: given a function and values of its arguments, can I assess the type of every intermediate variable and return type?

for example:

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
     intermediate_1 = arg1 + arg2
     intermediate_2 = str(arg1) + str(arg2)
     return str(intermediate_1) + intermediate_2
```

given that: `arg1 = 3` and `arg2 = 4`, 
what is a good way to find:

1. `type(intermediate_1)`
2. `type(intermediate_2)`
3. type of value returned by the `func`

What I have done so far is:

1. Read the python file as `str` using `with open('path/to/file.py', 'r')...`
2. Extract the functions using the `ast` module (so I have the full string body of the function).

Then using `type(eval('arg1 + arg2'))` to mark the type of `intermediate_1` as an `int`.

While this works, and I can loop over each line of the function and repeat the same, I wish to avoid `eval` as much as possible. <s>It appears to be harmless because it is wrapped by the `type()` but</s> I would be glad to use `ast` for doing something similar. `ast.literal_eval('arg1 + arg2')` failed to give same results. I could go about using string formatting techniques but then the line `ast.literal_eval('str(3) + str(4)')` doesn't parse either.

So is there a better way to do the same thing I have done with `eval`?

Comment: "It appears to be harmless because it is wrapped by the `type()`" - that doesn't make it harmless at all. `__import__('os').system('install ransomware or something')` will run arbitrary shell commands whether or not you call `type` on the return value.

Comment: I knew I wasn't aware of the things that can go wrong but I know there would be something :) hence "appears"

Comment: The type of `intermediate_2` cannot be determined statically even if you assume that the args are integers, because it is dependent on what `str` is defined to do. Assuming it is the default Python `str()` function is just that: an assumption. And you know what happens when you assume. The only reliable way to determine types is to run the code and see what you get.